# How do I add a dependency via grape?

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I want to play around with [NekoHtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), in Groovy. I thought of adding it via [Grape](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape).

I tried this way :

```
@GrabResolver(root="http://net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml")
```

in my Groovy code.

But it is throwing an error like this :

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/anto/Groovy/webScrape/webFetch.groovy: 3: unexpected token:  @ line 3, column 1.
```

The  [NekoHtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) can be found in Maven over [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml).

### Edit:

Now I have a code like this :

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.15')
import org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser
def url = 'http://java.sun.com'
def html = new XmlSlurper(new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parse(url)
def bolded = html.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'B' }
def out = bolded.A*.text().collect{ it.trim() }
out.removeAll([''])
out[2..5].each{ println it }
```

which throws the error like this :

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser
```

Couldn't able to figure out what this error states.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.15')
```

Then it should resolve from maven

Comment: +1 this works...But there is an another problem..I edited my question.

Comment: @ant can you try 1.9.15 (the latest version)?

Comment: Sadly, it was a problem with my Groovy installation files. I re-installed it and works well.. Thanks for the answer :)